# Using website to stop and launch applications on same machine

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, windows

I am in the process of setting up a website for users to sign up for accounts to access applications on a server running Windows Server 2019 with `IIS, MySQL, PHP,` and `FastCGI`.

The website works fine, the applications work fine, but it becomes rather tedious to have to login via RDP to restart an application if it hangs up, needs a manual update, etc. I have tried searching via google, and came up empty on this, but is there a way via `php, jquery/AJAX, etc.,` to click a button on my website's admin panel to send a command to Windows to shutdown and/or restart an application?

Example:

Let's say I have my website located at `C:/webroot/htdocs/" and an application at "C:/servers/server1/server.exe`

I want to send a command from the website to close any active windows for `server.exe` (the console window(s)) if I hit "Stop Server" on the webpage. If I hit "Start Server" it will send a command to launch the `server.exe` program. Finally, if I hit "Restart Server" it will perform the stop action, followed by the start action in a single click.

Is this possible without needing to purchase any type of third-party application?

I know there are cron jobs, but I am not sure exactly how to utilize them, especially in this type of scenario.

Comment: Consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for this specific question. Hopefully you will find something or working code with the information you have provided.

Comment: I actually have tried searching google and reddit, and both came back empty.  Either I am using wrong search keywords, or it's not something typically done via a website (Which I know it is due to multiple server hosting companies have this type of feature to manage your servers).

Comment: PHP is a server side language. Therefore, it can execute system commands using `shell_exec()`. So, what you need to do is send AJAX request to your PHP script, which will then execute any system commands. Please see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php